# Navigating to relative path in Angular app served through NGINX

Tags: angular, nginx

I am serving my Angular app through NGINX. The frontend should be accessible at `http://localhost/` and its backend at `http://localhost/api/`. My config mostly works, but I have an issue with a relative path from a href in the UI.

```
<a href="/api/someRoute">Click me</a>
```

The NGINX config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root html;
        try_files $uri$args /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9977/api;
    }
}
```

The problem I have is when I click the element I am redirected to the base address, so I assume NGINX falls back to serving index.html, but when I open the link in a new tab I get the correct page, which is just a string returned by the API.

I initially had `try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;`, but I removed the `$uri$args/` bit because when I build my app I get some extra folders and refreshing would not work for some paths (e.g. I had a users folder and refreshing while on `http://localhost/users` would not work).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9977;
    }

    location / { # Always at the end (NGinx apply priority, this rule is like wildcard)
        root html;
        try_files $uri$args /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change anything

Comment: I edit: remove `/api` after `:9977`. And add `/` at the end line `location /api`